# Save and pass to function list of template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates, callback, variadic-templates

I want to save and pass list of template arguments to function.
Like `std::thread` passes arguments to a thread. Types of arguments are templated and arguments count is not static.

Example, how it will work:

```
class CallbackList {
public:
    Callback(/* Type of list of template args */ args) {
        this->saved_args = args;
    }


    void Call() {
        this->callback(saved_args);
    }
private:
    /* Type of list of template args */ saved_args;

    CallbackType callback;
}
```

Or how can I implement that:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class CallbackList {
public:
    using CallbackPrototype = /* some prototype */;

    void RegisterCallback(CallbackPrototype callback, Args... args) {
        CallbackInfo callback_info;
        callback_info.callback = callback;
        callback_info.args = { args... };
        this->callbacks.push_back(callback_info);
    }

    void Call() {
        for (CallbackInfo& callback_info : this->callbacks)
            callback_info.callback(callback_info.args);
    }

private:
    struct CallbackInfo {
        CallbackPrototype callback;
        /* what type should be here? tuple? args count are not static */ args;
    };

    std::vector<CallbackInfo> callbacks;
}
```

It is possible?
How can I implement it?

Comment: Are you okay with making `Callback` a class template or are you going to be storing different callback objects in a single container?

Comment: you are looking for variadic templates. Its a broad topic, I suggest you to look at some examples eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: How is the actual `callback` set? It's never initialized here.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I can make the class templated
@AndyG, it's example, `callback` field will be initialized

I also added second example, closer to my real task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want your callback to depend on the types of the arguments you have to use some kind of type erasure. You can, for example, use `std::function` from `<functional>`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class Lazy_Callback
{
public:
  template <typename F, typename ...Args>
  Lazy_Callback(F && f, Args && ...args)
  : _fun([=]() { return f(args...); })
  { }
    
  void call() const
  {
    _fun();
  }
protected:
private:
  std::function<void()> _fun;
};

void print_int(int x)
{
  std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  Lazy_Callback lc(print_int, 5);
  
  lc.call();
}
```

If the callback can be templated then you can use `std::tuple` to store your arguments:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>



template <typename F, typename ...Args>
class Lazy_Callback
{
public:
  template <typename ...Ts>
  Lazy_Callback(F f, Ts && ...ts)
  : _f(f), _args(ts...)
  { }
  
  void call() const
  {
    return std::apply(_f, _args);
  }
  
protected:
private:
  F _f;
  std::tuple<Args...> _args;
};



template <typename F, typename ...Ts>
Lazy_Callback<F, std::decay_t<Ts>...> make_callback(F && f, Ts && ...ts)
{
  return { std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Ts>(ts)... };
}

void print_int(int x)
{
  std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  auto lc = make_callback(print_int, 5);
  
  lc.call();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)? Here is a simple example that you could probably expand on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void printSum(const T1& a, const T2& b)
{
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const auto callback = std::bind(&printSum<int, int>, 1, 2);

    // ...
    
    callback();
}
```

Comment: I added second example, closer to my real problem. It should be dynamically, stored in memory. It is possible?